# ArcMap 10 - Viewshed Analysis - Input Type

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap

Hopefully someone can tell me if I am missing something here. I am hoping to built a TIN in ArcScene and run some view shed analysis on it, simple enough but I need to add building heights to the TIN, this was done through an ArcGIS Script. The problem is I can't seem to get the TIN as the input surface using ArcMap 10 viewshed anlysis in the 3D or Spatial Analyst. Has ESRI removed this parameter completely from version 10?

Answer (score 1):

**Line of Sight** in 3D Analyst takes TIN, Terrain or Raster as input to determine visibility between observer and target points. (Multipatch feature, perhaps representing the buildings, can also be added). If targets are not visible from observer, the tool **outputs points marking the obstructions**.

**Viewshed** in 3D Analyst only takes in **raster as input**. THis is a cell based process. **Output is a raster of "visible" cells**.

You might need to convert your input TIN to raster to run the Viewshed analysis. As far as I know raster was always the input for this type of analysis.